# Were `do...while` loops left out of CoffeeScript...?

Tags: coffeescript

In CoffeeScript, the `while` loop comes standard:

```
while x()
   y()
```

However, the following<sup>1</sup> doesn't work:

```
do
  y()
while x()
```

And this is simply sugar for the first example:

```
y() while x()
```

Does CoffeeScript come with a built-in loop that executes at least once?

<sup>1</sup>As an aside, `do` *is* a keyword — it's used to call anonymous functions.

Comment: OT, but I loled at the description of the `coffeescript` tag. :)

Comment: one should ask oneself whether a given construct is very desirable at all. the important distinction between `while` and `do...while` is that the loop body is executed once, as the condition is only checked after the loop body has executed. in CS you can easily do that using a `do...break if...` or `do...break unless...` construct which reads just as cleanly & *is more flexible* since the `break` can occur on any line in the loop body. this also applies to similar constructs like pascal's `repeat...until`.

Comment: @flow `do...break if...` incurs IIFE penalty

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The CoffeeScript documentation says:

> The only low-level loop that CoffeeScript provides is the while loop.

I don't know of a built-in loop that executes at least once, so I guess the alternative is

```
loop
  y()
  break if x()
```

Comment: +1 That's what I feared. A quick web search reveals several blogs mention CoffeeScript's support for "do-while" loops, but those blogs certainly appear to be wrong.

Comment: Note that this simulates `do`-`until`; you need `break unless` for `do`-`while`.

Comment: `loop` is more low level than `while`, is it not? That unlinked quote sounds wrong.

Answer (score 24):

I know that this answer is very old, but since I entered here via Google, I thought someone else might as well.

To construct a do...while loop equivalent in CoffeeScript I think that this syntax emulates it the best and easiest and is very readable:

```
while true
   # actions here
   break unless # conditions here
```

Comment: `while true` can be written as `loop` (and is more descriptive: you're constructing a loop, and it doesn't continue as long as `true`)

Comment: @1j01 Retrospectively I agree that `loop` is semantically better after nearly two years, but this is an alternative and after writing my JS with CoffeeScript for a few years it is still my preferred method, probably just out of a habit.

Answer (score 16):

Your guess is correct: There is no `do-while` equivalent in CoffeeScript. So you'd typically write

```
y()
y() while x()
```

If you find yourself doing this often, you might define a helper function:

```
doWhile = (func, condition) ->
  func()
  func() while condition()
```

Comment: Why this over `loop; y(); break unless x();`?

Comment: Good question. I haven't seen `loop` used very much in the wild, but this is the most sensible use case for it.

Answer (score 3):

I found this could be accomplished through a short circuit conditional:

```
flag = y() while not flag? or x()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a project where I simply force the condition to evaluate at the end of the loop, then terminate at the beginning.

```
# set the 'do' variable to pass the first time
do = true
while do

  # run your intended code
  x()

  # evaluate condition at the end of
  # the while code block
  do = condition

# continue code
```

It's not very elegant, but it does keep you from defining a new function just for your while code block and running it twice. There generally is a way to code around the do...while statements, but for those time that you can't you have a simple solution.

Comment: `do` is reserved word in CoffeeScript. This would really confuse the reader.