# How to adjust the variable scope in while loop for matching all regex in CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, coffeescript, scope

I'm having a little trouble with while loops in coffeescript.

The original function is as the following and [the source is this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8877261/751969):

```
// Return all pattern matches with captured groups
RegExp.prototype.execAll = function(string) {
    var match = null;
    var matches = new Array();
    while (match = this.exec(string)) {
        var matchArray = [];
        for (i in match) {
            if (parseInt(i) == i) {
                matchArray.push(match[i]);
            }
        }
        matches.push(matchArray);
    }
    return matches;
}
```

It works as intended. I have converted it via [js2coffee](http://js2coffee.org/) and the coffee script is:

```
# Return all pattern matches with captured groups
RegExp::execAll = (string) ->

  matches = new Array()
  match = null
  while match = @exec(string) 
    matchArray = new Array()
    for i of match
      matchArray.push match[i]  if parseInt(i) is i
    matches.push matchArray
  matches
```

Which compiles to:

```
RegExp.prototype.execAll = function(string) {
  var i, match, matchArray, matches;
  matches = new Array();
  match = null;
  while (match = this.exec(string)) {
    matchArray = new Array();
    for (i in match) {
      if (parseInt(i) === i) {
        matchArray.push(match[i]);
      }
    }
    matches.push(matchArray);
  }
  return matches;
};
```

The result is:

```
[
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  []
]
```

I think this doesn't work because of the variable scope since the only difference I can see is this line:

```
RegExp.prototype.execAll = function(string) {
  var i, match, matchArray, matches;
```

versus the original:

```
RegExp.prototype.execAll = function(string) {
    var match = null;
    var matches = new Array();
    while (match = this.exec(string)) {
        var matchArray = [];
```

Notice how `matchArray` is scoped out... I couldn't find a way around this, but as I was researching I found these questions [Were `do...while` loops left out of CoffeeScript...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052946/were-do-while-loops-left-out-of-coffeescript) and [How do I declare a variable in a specific scope in coffeescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005505/how-do-i-declare-a-variable-in-a-specific-scope-in-coffeescript) and I'm pretty much out of ideas here... Any other way of matching all with regexp other than this while loop (by the way I have tried `\gm` flags and it still hits only one match)? Or is there a way of getting this scope right in coffee script?

The whole Coffee Script code is :

```
fs = require 'fs'

text = fs.readFileSync('test.md','utf8')

#console.log text

regex = /^(?:@@)(\w+):(.*.)/gm
# Return all pattern matches with captured groups
RegExp::execAll = (string) ->

  matches = new Array()
  match = null
  while match = @exec(string) 
    matchArray = new Array()
    for i of match
      matchArray.push match[i]  if parseInt(i) is i
    matches.push matchArray
  matches

res = regex.execAll text
#console.log regex.exec text
console.log (JSON.stringify(res, null, "  ") )
```

And the Javascript **that works** is this:

```
var fs, regex, res, text;

fs = require('fs');

text = fs.readFileSync('test.md', 'utf8');

regex = /^(?:@@)(\w+):(.*.)/gm;

// Return all pattern matches with captured groups
RegExp.prototype.execAll = function(string) {
    var match = null;
    var matches = new Array();
    while (match = this.exec(string)) {
        var matchArray = [];
        for (i in match) {
            if (parseInt(i) == i) {
                matchArray.push(match[i]);
            }
        }
        matches.push(matchArray);
    }
    return matches;
}

res = regex.execAll(text);

//console.log(regex.exec(text));

console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, "  "));
```

Comment: Just a note: On the result there are 9 empty arrays for 9 actual matches (those are filled with the working javascript code)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The actual problem is not what you think it is. The actual problem is that the `==` compiled to `===`. Here's how you fix it:

```coffee
# Return all pattern matches with captured groups
RegExp::execAll = (string) ->
  matches = []
  while match = @exec string
    matches.push(group for group in match)
  matches
```

But you may be wondering why `===` doesn't work. Thus, I present to you:

## Why `===` doesn't work (in this case)

`parseInt(i) == i` was supposed to determine if `i` is a string that represents an integer. You can try that in JavaScript on a few values and see that it works. `parseInt(i)` is a number, whereas `i` is a string. In JavaScript, if you're using `==` on a string and a number, it will implicitly coerce and the test will work as you might expect. This implicit coercion is often unexpected, so CoffeeScript disallows it from happening by having no equivalent of the `==` operator, translating `==` (and `is`) into `===`, which first compares types. In that case, the number and the string will never be equal, so the `if`'s condition is never met, so nothing is ever pushed onto the array.

Comment: I have just found out that if you do something like `if \`"string" == "string"\` then return true` you can have `==` signs. So between `\`here\`` you can write literal javascript

Comment: @Logan: You could indeed do that, but you might want to put the operands into variables first so you can use CoffeeScript syntax in the operands. Regardless, I think you'll agree that for this particular case, using an idiomatic translation is better than trying to literally translate it.

Comment: I agree with you on idiomatic translation. However I don't understand how to use CoffeeScript syntax in the operands by putting them into variables. Do you mean `if \`str == str2\` then return true` ?

Comment: @Logan: I'm saying if you wanted to use CoffeeScript syntax of the operands (like, say, `personA?.name == personB?.name`), but wanted to use `==` rather than `===` in the translated JavaScript, you might have to use the CoffeeScript `personAName = personA?.name; personBName = personB?.name; \`personAName == personBName\``.